# How to run Vue.js 3 app via docker using TypeScript and Vite?

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, vue.js, vite

I am struggling while trying to dockerize a Vue.js 3 application using Vite and TypeScript. Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18.12.1-alpine3.16 AS build-stage

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./
RUN yarn install

COPY . .
RUN yarn build-only

FROM nginx:stable-alpine AS production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 5137
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

If I tried to build the image I get the following error output:

```
[+] Building 117.0s (12/13)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 318B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:stable-alpine                                                                                                                                                                                               4.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18.12.1-alpine3.16                                                                                                                                                                                           4.0s
 => CACHED [production-stage 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:stable-alpine@sha256:2366ede62d2e26a20f7ce7d0294694fe52b166107fd346894e4658dfb5273f9c                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [build-stage 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/node:18.12.1-alpine3.16@sha256:9eff44230b2fdcca57a73b8f908c8029e72d24dd05cac5339c79d3dedf6b208b                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    6.1s
 => => transferring context: 2.20MB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  6.1s
 => CACHED [build-stage 2/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [build-stage 3/6] COPY package.json ./                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [build-stage 4/6] RUN yarn install                                                                                                                                                                                                                             102.3s
 => [build-stage 5/6] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       3.0s
 => ERROR [build-stage 6/6] RUN yarn build-only                                                                                                                                                                                                                      1.4s
------
 > [build-stage 6/6] RUN yarn build-only:
#12 1.348 ✘ [ERROR] Cannot start service: Host version "0.16.4" does not match binary version "0.16.14"
#12 1.348
#12 1.348 1 error
#12 1.355 failed to load config from /app/vite.config.ts
#12 1.356 error during build:
#12 1.356 Error: The service was stopped: write EPIPE
#12 1.356     at /app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1136:25
#12 1.356     at responseCallbacks.<computed> (/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:694:9)
#12 1.356     at afterClose (/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:684:28)
#12 1.356     at /app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:2077:11
#12 1.356     at onwriteError (node:internal/streams/writable:418:3)
#12 1.356     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn build-only]: exit code: 1
```

I am working on the fork of that [repo](https://github.com/logue/vite-vuetify-ts-starter). You can check the package.json in there etc.

What am I doing wrong?? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Looks like you have a dependency version mismatch, try to upgrade your packages to last patch version and regenerate your yarn-lock.json :)

Comment: I can't find any dependency having given version in my package.json (0.16.4). Also if I tried to run "vite build" on my local - it works without any problem

Comment: Could you check your yarn-lock.json file for this version? It's likely a nested dependency. On local it may work because you already have a node_modules folder filled in, but for your docker build, it does a fresh install.

Comment: I've tried to there are some references, however after changing them to 0.16.14 still having the same error. I've also tried to remove node_modules directory from my local and setup the app using the same commands as in dockerfile - on local it works

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem, my goal was to start a simple docker-compose file for development and traefik as my proxy. After several trials and errors, I was able to make it run. Below is my configuration.

here's the **compose** setup

```
services:
  ....
  app:
    image: app
    build:
    context: .
    env_file: ".env"
    volumes:
       - '.:/app'
       - /app/node_modules/ 
    networks:
      - common
    expose:
      - 5173
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.services.app.loadbalancer.server.port=5173"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app.rule=Host(`example.com`)"
```

Some explanation:

***/app/node_modules/***  - ignore node_modules, When using M? processor and the docker container is using linux. *(Specifically the "esbuild-darwin-arm64" package is present but this platform
needs the "esbuild-linux-arm64" package instead)*

***xxx.server.port=5173*** - let traefik know what port to use, just added it just in case even though traefik is smart enough to know what port is being expose (not bad to be more specific)

here's the **dockerFile**

```
FROM node:16    
WORKDIR /app
# install vite globally
RUN npm install -g vite
# copy all filtes
COPY . .    
# install all deps
RUN yarn install

# vite default port
EXPOSE 5173    
CMD ["yarn", "run", "dev"]
```

and finally, you need to configure **vite.config.js** to expose the host because when I don't do this I keep getting a bad gateway error.

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import path from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    }
  },
  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0'
  }
});
```

While in production you can just build `yarn build` then use nginx to expose the `/dist/index.html` file

Hope this will be a good help!